# Character encoding between MySQL, C# and in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a db with content like

```
  https://pastebin.com/LRgTqHjN
```

(stored with the wrong encoding)

Save it to a file record.sql

```
    mysql -u root --password=root enctest < record.sql
```

get the same garbage as input;

```
   mysqldump  -u root --password=root enctest
```

but if you add;

```
   mysqldump  -u root --password=root --default-character-set=latin1 enctest
```

it shows the correct content.

I want to reproduce the latter behaviour in C#, I use the following code:

```
  "MySqlConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=enctest;user=root;password=root",
```

and

```
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand($"select * from siteTxt", conn);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = (MySqlDataReader)(await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()))
            {
                     for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
                     {
                           
                                    row.Add(reader.GetString(i));
                     }
           }
```

But that shows the same garbage as:

```
   mysqldump  -u root --password=root enctest
```

How can I make it show the same output as the second mysqldump?

Note: the real table is a few terabytes in size; I cannot just dump it and reimport it (which would fix the issue) which is why I need to fix it in the C# reader.

Update: for viewing, a solution that works is to change the select query to:

CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(`{column}` USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4)

per string type column which obviously is less than ideal, but it works well.

Comment: So look for other misconfigurations. Because those UTF8 bytes remain UTF8 bytes. And that has **nothing to do with any problem in C#. Post your code and an actual reproduction of the problem**. Something that actually produces mangled text

Comment: With all databases I have that properly stored UTF8 as UTF8, it works just fine in my console without anything added. It's just this db that behaves differently. phpmyadmin shows the same issue with this db.

Comment: `msg` is already a string. It doesn't need any encoding conversion.

Comment: This is the code that produces the problem; it's a straight copy/paste.

Comment: YES BECAUSE YOU EXPLICITLY MANGLE THE TEXT BY CONVERTING IT TO LATIN1. The second snippet does nothing but mangle the text. What does `msg` contain before it gets mangled?

Comment: `byte[] utfBytes = iso.GetBytes(msg);` no, those aren't "UTF" bytes, they are mangled data. [Read the table of Latin1 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). No Greek, no Chinese there. `iso.GetBytes(msg)` is going to replace *all* characters outside that range with `?`.

Comment: I'm saying I played around with that; I removed it again because it does not work. So it's not using that convert code; it's just straight getting from the db; here a dump of a record from the db; https://pastebin.com/LRgTqHjN

Comment: That's already mangled. The dump you posted contains `Î£ÏÎ½Î´ÎµÏƒÎ·` instead of the proper contents.

Comment: Thatt's what's in the db, but if you import it into mysql and you use the mysql cli with --default-character-set=latin1 it works fine, so it's possible to get it out properly.

Comment: I added the steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Not exactly, as this has nothing to do with .NET. You have to post the steps that would end up storing mangled text in a MySQL database - create the table with the same encodings, insert text so it gets mangled the same way. This means you should include the MySQL dumps in the question, not the C# code. You have to make `MySqlConnection` to do the conversion. If you try to do that afterwards you'd be trying to reverse *two* conversions*. Perhaps you can add `;charset=utf8` or `;charset=latin1` in your connection string? `utf8mb4` is also available

Comment: I posted the connection string and the dump as well; you can totally reproduce this locally (I understand you have something better to do :). The simplicity of this is that the data *is* wrong in the database and I inherited it so I have no clue why / how it is wrong, but mysql-client/dump can get it out correctly, so C# should be able to do that too. I edited the question to be short and allow to reproduce exactly.

Comment: Show us the garbage.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for typical cases.

Comment: Show us the hex of what is in the table -- `SELECT HEX(col) ...`

Comment: `Î£ÏÎ½Î´ÎµÏƒÎ` is "mojibake", possibly for Greek.  I see `εσ` at the end.

Comment: Do not use latin1 -- Greek cannot be represented in latin1.

Comment: `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`) can handle Greek.  A few other charsets can handle Greek, but you should go for utf8mb4.

Comment: The request for HEX will determine whether it was mangled _going into_ the database or _coming out_.

Comment: The dump uses latin1 -- bad.  The connection does not specify a charset -- bad.

Comment: `CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('ÎµÏƒ' USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4)` gives  'εσ', but you should _not_ have to use that in production code.